# IntelliJ Plugin to view NPM dependency tree (visualise package.json)

Tags: npm, intellij-idea, dependencies, package.json

In IntelliJ there are plugins to see whole maven dependencies tree (which shows also transitive/indirect dependencies).
For instance this one:

[image]

Is there similiar plugin for showing NPM tree, read from package.json file? Something which could visualize the output of the command: "npm ls --all" or any other command which presents the tree of dependencies.